# How to handle string pattern categories

Tags: python, regex, pandas

### The problem

I have a column in dataframe that has 4 different string patterns like:

```
COLUMN |  
'NE=123'  
'NE=123, FR=4'  
'NE=123, FR=4, S=5, CP=6'  
'NE=123, FR=4, S=5, CP=6, SC=78, PP=99'
```

I want to create column to encode patterns so that the output will be like:

```
COLUMN                                |  CATEGORY
AA=123                                | A
AA=123, BB=4                          | AB
AA=123, BB=4, CC=5, DD=6              | ABCD
AA=123, BB=4, CC=5, DD=6, EE=78, FF=99| ABCDEF
```

I tried to see if that worked smth like

```
A = 'AA'
B = 'BB'  
C = ['CC', 'DD']
D = ['EE', 'FF']
df[df['COLUMNS'].str.contains(A, B, '|'.join(C)==False, '|'.join(D)==False)]
```

But I also get the rows with C and D included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a combination of functions in a lambda:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['NE=123','NE=123, FR=4' ,'NE=123, FR=4, S=5, CP=6',
                               'NE=123, FR=4, S=5, CP=6, SC=78, PP=99'],
                    'index':[0,1,2,3]})
print(df)
df['category'] = df['column_1'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(list(set(re.findall(r'[A-Z]+',x))))))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                column_1  index     category
0                                 NE=123      0           NE
1                           NE=123, FR=4      1         FRNE
2                NE=123, FR=4, S=5, CP=6      2      CPFRNES
3  NE=123, FR=4, S=5, CP=6, SC=78, PP=99      3  CPFRNEPPSSC
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't produce third category. I edited the startpost with the example of real data, dunno whether it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

DataFrame:

```
d={'COLUMN': 
['AA=123' ,
'AA=123, BB=4',  
'AA=123, BB=4, CC=5, DD=6 ', 
'AA=123, BB=4, CC=5, DD=6, EE=78, FF=99']}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Function to find pattern:

```
def f(s):
  m=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

  p = []
  r=''

  for x in s:
    if x in m and x not in p:
      p.append(x)
      r+=str(x)

  return r
```

Create `category` column:

```
df['Category']=df['COLUMN'].apply(lambda x :  f(x))
```

Output:

```
    COLUMN                                  Cateory
0   AA=123                                  A
1   AA=123, BB=4                            AB
2   AA=123, BB=4, CC=5, DD=6                ABCD
3   AA=123, BB=4, CC=5, DD=6, EE=78, FF=99  ABCDEF
```

Comment: for some reason it produces empty strings as a result

Comment: strange,check if if my data frame same as yours

Comment: I edited the startpost with example of real data that produced the error.

Comment: ok,the `m` in function `f()` don't have all the aplhabets only upto H,that is why it is giving empty result,check if it work for you know